# При очищении остается 0 в input value React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Разрабатывая компонент столкнулся с проблемой - input value при удаление значения из input до конца не удаляется - всегда остается 0. Логика компонента следующая - input получает начальное значения value из Redux store. Изменяя значения в одном из input-от ми диспатчим store и получаем значения value для второго input-a. Все работает, кроме полного очищения input. А используя defaultValue разрывается связь между ними. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить?

```
class _Input extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeValue = this.onChangeValue.bind(this);
      }
      onChangeValue(e){
        this.props.onChangeValue(e.target.value);
      }
      render() {
        return(
           <span>
            <p className="input-name">{this.props.name}</p>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder={this.props.name}
              //defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
              value={this.props.value}
              onChange={this.onChangeValue}
            />
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder={this.props.name}
              //defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
              value={this.props.value}
              onChange={this.onChangeValue}
            />
          </span>
        )
      }
    }
    function mapStateToProps (state) {
      return {
        value: state.startAngle,
      }
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        onChangeValue: (value) => {
          dispatch(changeStartAngle(+value))
        }
      }
    }
const Input = connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  mapDispatchToProps
)(_Input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> dispatch(changeStartAngle(+value))
> ```

В этом месте пустая строка превращается в 0 унарным плюсом.
Надо обрабатывать пустую строку как-то иначе, например

```
dispatch(changeStartAngle(+value || ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value={minPrice === 0 ? "" : minPrice}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]